# Delete all english letters in string

Tags: c#, string

I need to delete all english letters in a string.

I wrote the following code:

```
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
foreach(var letter in test)
{   
    if(letter >= 'a' && letter <= 'z')
        continue;
    str.Append(letter); }
```

What is the fastest way?

Comment: Don't you mean Latin letters? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_alphabet

Comment: Why does this part of your program need to be fast? Have you profiled it?

Comment: @Bazzz - the Wikipedia page implies that "English Alphabet" is probably more correct - the classical latin alphabet doesn't contain J or W.  :)

Comment: @Bazzz: Supporting @Will A's comment, the English alphabet is Latin-based, but not the same as the Latin alphabet.

Comment: @BoltClock - +1 - quid pro quo.

Comment: this can surely be done with a Linq query: slowest to run and hardest to read!!

Answer (score 2):

use Regex replace method, and give it [a-z]|[A-Z]

Comment: OP wasn't clear on what is meant by 'fastest' but in terms of execution speed, this is certain to be slower than the version posted.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var str = test.Where(item => item < 'A' || item > 'z' || (item > 'Z' && item < 'a'));
```

Comment: Your expression only matches the characters `[, \, ], ^, _` and the backtick. What about digits or the other punctuation characters? Also, this returns an `IEnumerable<char>`, not a `string`.

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi: The provided condition here is match the condition the OP has provided in the question.

Comment: @Akram, nope, the questioner's code only excludes lower-case letters and matches all the other characters.

Comment: @Akram, sorry, that still doesn't work (it will match all the characters). Did you test the code in your updated answer?

Comment: @Akram, `item < 'a' || item > 'Z'` will match all characters. `item > 'z' && item < 'A'` won't match any character. Since the two conditions are `OR`ed together, all the characters will be matched.

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi: I guess what you are trying to say here is that AZ characters come before az characters ? Is that right ??

Comment: @Akram, yup, that's right. Were you thinking in [EBCDIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Binary_Coded_Decimal_Interchange_Code)? :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this method to do such execution....

public static string RemoveSpecialCharacters(string str)

{

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (char c in str)

    {

        if ((c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') || (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z'))

            continue;

        else

            sb.Append(c);


    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```